# How to enter options when using an input palette

Tags: front-end, palettes

```
Integrate[1/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(5/2), {x, 0, b}, {y, 0, l}, 
  GenerateConditions -> False]
```

We can type in the above expression easily. But if someone new to *Mathematica* is using an input palette to enter the expression, how can this person also enter the option?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't be done. This can be verified by converting the input form expression into standard form.

1. Start with

   ```
   Integrate[1/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(5/2), {x, 0, b}, {y, 0, l}, 
     GenerateConditions -> False]
   ```
2. Select the expression and click on **Standard Form** in the **Convert To** sub-menu of the **Cell** menu. (That choice will be checked as if it were active, but ignore that.)

You will get

[image: int-1]

Now do the same thing with

```
Integrate[1/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(5/2), {x, 0, b}, {y, 0, l}]
```

This time you will get

[image: int-2]

which is what an input palette would produce. I assert that if the form with the option had a pretty-print equivalent, the procedure I outlined would have produced it. But it didn't. Q.E.D.